# FK de MySQL o posición de sentencias

Tags: mysql

alguien me ayuda no puedo por la FK en la tabla productos para relacionar la tabla proveedores.... mando mysql bd

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cursoj2ee.productos; 
CREATE TABLE cursoj2ee.productos ( 
ID_Producto int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
ID_Provee int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
Descripcion varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
Cantidad varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
Precio varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Proovee) ACA MI ERROR ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2021 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cursoj2ee.proveedores; 
CREATE TABLE cursoj2ee.proveedores ( 
ID_Provee int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Fecha_Ingreso datetime NOT NULL, 
Nombre varchar(45) NOT NULL, Domicilio varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
Telefono varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Provee) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCR
```

Intento crear la FK con

`FOREIGN KEY(ID_Provee) REFERENCES proveedores (ID_provee)`

Comment: Hola, disculpa, no se entiende cuál es tu problema. Qué error encontraste? Cómo intentaste crear la FK? La creación de productos no funciona como está (qué es KEY?)

Comment: no puedo asociar la tabla Productos cn la tabla proveedores me salta error cuando quiero agregar la FK ...

Comment: Vale. Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el código que estás usando para intentar crearla y qué error te sale.

Comment: ah perdon FOREIGN KEY(ID_Provee) REFERENCES proveedores (ID_provee)

Comment: Qué error te sale? Te ayudo añadiendo eso a tu pregunta. Por favor, edítala, que en los comentarios se pierden las cosas

Comment: el sistema realiza una lectura secuencial de los comandos que se le envían en este caso la tabla proveedores no existe cuando se trata de crear esa referencia, por lo que no puede crear la misma cuando se lo indico

Comment: Si ves a que me refiero con que no es claro qué error tienes?

Comment: there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.

Comment: there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key...eeso me sale pero  ahora si logro poner la Fk en la tabla productos me deja, pero solo si saco el auto increment de ID_Provee y Id_Producto.

Answer (score 0):

No indicas qué error te da la BD al ejecutar tu script. Sin embargo, es necesario que crees en orden los objetos. Debe existir la tabla que referencias antes de referenciarla. En todas tus tablas el orden es importante. Así como, para hacer DROP deberás hacerlo en orden (inverso a la creación) para no pelear con validaciones de registros que quedarían huérfanos

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cursoj2ee.proveedores; 
CREATE TABLE cursoj2ee.proveedores ( 
ID_Provee int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Fecha_Ingreso datetime NOT NULL, 
Nombre varchar(45) NOT NULL, Domicilio varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
Telefono varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Provee) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2021 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cursoj2ee.productos; 
CREATE TABLE cursoj2ee.productos ( 
ID_Producto int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
ID_Provee int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
Descripcion varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
Cantidad varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
Precio varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Proovee) REFERENCES proveedores(ID_provee) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2021 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: soy nuevo aca por eso no se usar el blog....claro eso es lo que pasa ... hace referencia a que debo cambiar la posición de las sentencias. pero no se como me da error de sintaxis-... uso mysql query browser